# How do I get the proper indent for my else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

Using the Python 3.8.2 shell I receive the following error:

```
>>> age = 15
>>> if age > 17:
        print ("You can vote")
        else:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After reading up on if/else I understand the else statement must be at the same indent as the if statement, but when hitting Enter after the print statement the else falls underneath "print."

If I delete before the else to pull it to the left margin and then space over four times I get this error:

```
>>> age = 15
>>> if age > 17:
    print ("You can vote")
    else:

SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, if you don't understand this yet, you don't know Python. Do a tutorial first.

Comment: Pay close attention to how the `print` line is indented the first time, and how it is indented the second time. Also, the shell *does not actually look exactly like that*. Pay closer attention. Notice how when you hit Enter it fills in a `...`? That's carefully chosen to be the same width as the `>>>`, to avoid confusion about how much indentation there is.

Comment: Actually, hold on - are you using IDLE? I recommend not bothering with it, honestly. To use the Python shell, it's simpler to just use a `cmd`/`Terminal` window and run `python`; to edit .py files, use your preferred text editor (*not* word processor).

Comment: Thanks, Karl. I am using IDLE. I will try using your other recommended methodology instead and report back.

Comment: That worked Karl. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

In the shell, you can't add blank lines. Otherwise, here is how you do it:

```
>>> age = 15
>>> if age > 17:
...     print ("You can vote")
... else:
...     print ("You can't")
...
You can't
```

Answer (score 0):

The `>>>` prompt does not count as indentation. When you use the plain command-line version of Python, as you type each line of code in an `if` statement, the lines will be padded with `...` at the front, to avoid confusion about the amount of indentation. It appears that IDLE does not do this. (I strongly recommend not using it, in general - it doesn't do anything useful that isn't already done by simple tools you already have, and it does add subtle gotchas like this one.)

Since the `if` has zero indentation, the `else` should also have zero indentation. Also, you should use spaces consistently to indent; if the `print` is indented with a tab, then that does not match any number of spaces.

In any event, when typing a block of code at the interpreter prompt, blank lines are not permitted - a blank line is how you signal that the block is completed, and Python syntax requires that you put something inside the `else`.